# Removing reference from a child collection in MongooseJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that includes an array of child references:

```
const schemaSet = {
     userSchema: new Schema({ 
         name: { 
           type: String,
           required: true
         }
     }),

     groupSchema: new Schema({
          name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
          },
          members: [ {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
            ref: 'User'
          }]
     })
}
```

This is working fine in terms of being able to create groups and add users to them, but I find I can't remove a user from the group.

The closest I have got so far is this:

```
async removeUser(group, userId) {
    console.log("Before: group has "+group.members.length+" members");
    await group.members.pull({ _id : userId });
    console.log("After: group has "+group.members.length+" members");
    await group.save();
}
```

This logs out the correct size before and after the call and runs with no errors, but the next time I retrieve that group, the member is still there. I have tried using `remove` as well with much the same outcome.

I only want to remove the reference from the `members` collection, the User needs to persist. How do I persist the removal of the reference to a document?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to discover this. If you have a group model (created using `const Group = mongoose.model("Group", groupSchema)`), and the id of the user you want to remove from the group, you can use the following syntax: `const updatedGroup = await Group.findOneAndUpdate({ members: userId }, { $pull: { members: userId }}, {new: true, useFindAndModify: false});`
The third parameter in that function indicates that the updated document should be returned, and ensures that you don't get a warning. Actually, that syntax will only work if the group to user relationship is one to many (i.e. any user can only be in one group). If the relationships is many to many, I guess you would have to use the following:
`await Group.where({ members: userId}).update({ $pull: { members: userId }});`